# Simple AngularJS with CSS animation

Tags: css, angularjs

I have read a couple of tutorials online, but I can't seem to get a cross-browser working example together.

HTML:

```
<div ng-include="show ? 'views/registration/form_activation.html' : null" ng-animate class="drop-down"></div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ANIMATIONS */

.drop-down {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition:    all linear 1s;
  -ms-transition:     all linear 1s;
  -o-transition:      all linear 1s;
  transition:         all linear 1s;

  line-height: 100%;

}

.drop-down.ng-enter,
.drop-down.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
}

.drop-down.ng-enter-active,
.drop-down.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

What I would like to accomplish is that when the template is loaded with ng-include, it fades in from 0 to 100 opacity, and that it simultaneously opens like a dropdown (starting from 0, to full height that it needs). And vice versa when the form gets hidden.

The opacity already works, but changing the height does not, the div instantly appears with full height. Can some help me build the CSS with a cross-browser solution?

Comment: Use height in pixels...

Comment: I cannot use pixels, because I do not know how much height the elements will have. I also tried line-height from 0 to 100%, but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: give ng-animate a shot http://www.nganimate.org/

Comment: nganimate.org is outdated I think. I use angular 1.3

Answer (score 0):

you have to define `max-height` in px in `.drop-down` class to make it work.
you can put any high value to `max-height` in px as you are anyways not defining the height.

also define `overflow: hidden` in `.drop-down` so that content is hidden on transition of height.

worked for me.
example demo here :- http://plnkr.co/edit/rXQQHTogKzAG91xw3JUx?p=preview